# How to filter records for all rows?

Tags: t-sql, filter

I am designing a SQL query to extract all records from a given table.  But the trick here is that this logic is based on a numeric database field.  So there are 4 choices: 0,1,2,3.  If user selects 0,1, or 2, then my query returns rows with the specified value.  But if they choose 3, it should return all of the rows.  How do I do this in SQL?  I know if this was a string, I could do something like:
WHERE  = CASE WHEN  = 3 THEN '%' ELSE  END

But in this case,  is an integer.  Sounds relatively simple but I'm getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to do this:

```
select MyColumn
from   MyTable
where  ( MyValue = @MyParameter or @MyParameter = 3)
```

If your interested in better optimization, then you can do this, but it is less maintainable:

```
if (@MyParameter = 3)
    select MyColumn
    from MyTable
else
    select MyColumn
    from MyTable
    where MyValue = @MyParameter
```

If I were forced to implement this functionality, then I would probably do this, just to make things clear:

```
declare @AllRecords nchar(1)
if (@MyParameter = 3)
   set @AllRecords = N'Y'
else
   set @AllRecords = N'N'

select MyColumn
from MyTable
where (MyValue = @MyParameter or @AllRecords = N'Y')
```

Hopefully, I won't ever have to implement a system that mixes flags and data value in this way.

**UPDATED**

Here is a version that should work with your expanded requirements (this requires one of the newer versions of SQL Server, I think):

```
declare @SelectedLevels table (LevelId int not null primary key)
if @LevelId = 3
    insert into @SelectedLevels (LevelId) values (1), (2)
else if @LevelId = 5
    insert into @SelectedLevels (LevelId) values (0), (1), (2)
else
    insert into @SelectedLevels (LevelId) values (@LevelId)

select mt.MyColumn
from   MyTable mt
       inner join @SelectedLevels sl on sl.LevelId = MyTable.LevelId
```

Comment: Since u all are experts.  One more question I just realized.  If they choose param = 2, then it should include records where level = 0 or 1.  So it's the combination of these two levels.  How do I accomodate the all selection along with this combo logic?

Comment: @salvationishere - If 2 is a combination of 0 and 1, and 3 is a combination of 0, 1, and 2. Then what is the difference between 2 and 3?

Comment: Do you just want all records where the value is less-than-or-equal-to the input?

Comment: No.  Let me explain further.  There are unique rows for Levels 0, 1, and 2.  If they choose Level 3, then output should return both levels 1 and 2.  If they choose level 5, it should return 0,1,2.  Does that make more sense?

Comment: @salvationishere - I have updated the answer to address these new requirements.

Comment: Fantastic, Jeffrey!  You rock!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
 WHERE
 (
  <YOUR_COLUMN> = @InputValue OR
  3 = @InputValue
 )
```

Where @InputValue is the name of parameter sent to the query.

Comment: Cybernate, would u look at my comment below?

Comment: @salvationishere: As the condition keep increase its better to shift to a stored procedure that returns the data using if-else conditions in terms of understandable and maintainable queries. Explore that option

Answer (score 1):

```
if @Param = 3
begin
  select *
  from @T
end
else
if @Param = 2
begin
  select *
  from @T
  where id in (0,1)
end
else
begin
  select *
  from @T
  where id = @Param
end
```

Comment: Thakns for ur help but could u look at my comment below?  (New issue).

Comment: i c where u r going with this: writing separate queries for each case.  I suppose I could do it that way, but I'd prefer to encapsulate this logic in one WHERE statement.  Could u look at my comment above to Jeffrey?

Comment: @salvationishere, I think it is hard to understand what you actually want. It would probably be best if you modified your question with what you have put in comments and it would also be helpful if you could provide some sample data with expected output. The answer I have given (so far) I think you should put in a stored procedure. I believe that the query optimizer can do a far better job with separate queries than one query with a complicated where clause.